# Does this mean the port 9000 is not available?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
In [1]: import requests                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: requests.get('http://localhost:9000').ok                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[2]: False

In [3]: requests.get('http://localhost:9000/ping').ok                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[3]: False
```

In my iPython environment, I executed the above, and it displays the False, does this mean the 9000 port not available?

However, on my another computer, I did the same thing, and it printed out the True. I am debugging a piece of code, and trying to figure out what might go wrong.

The output of .content on failed and successful computers:

```
In [2]: requests.get('http://localhost:9000/ping').content                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2]: b'pong\n'
```

This is successful.

The failed request returns a very lengthy message, which includes:

```
permission-denied. The administrator may not allow this cache to make direct connections to origin servers.
```

Comment: I think it could be anything other than `200`

Comment: As per the [Doc](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/api/#requests.Response.ok) it **Returns `True` if `status_code` is less than 400, `False` if not.**

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM What does this really mean? On my computer when it returns false, the requests is timed out, on another computer when the same program runs and returns true, the requests is successful. So I was trying to figure what's the issue. Is it possible that on the failed computer, there is a firewall to block it?

Comment: Did you checked the `status_code` in both the cases?

Comment: 200 & 500 respectively.

Comment: Here is a [blog](https://realpython.com/python-requests/) which might help you understand

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas it helps, but it doesn't suggestion anything that could solve my issue. I tried a few other possible port other than 9000, and they fail too.

Comment: This may happen due to any service running at port 9000 in the system which is giving you an error while the other system the service is returning a success value. Print `.content` and check what does it return.

Comment: Please see content.

Comment: The error is not related to your Python code but to whatever service you expect to be working properly on port 9000

Comment: The administor of the server needs to allow access throught port 9000? It complains about Squid cache.